# Bootstrap 5 + Masonry-Layout JS Margin

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm having issues with margins using Masonry-Layout [(A JS library)](https://masonry.desandro.com/). This is what Bootstrap 5 recommends using.

It works as intended using [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/lwQ9eKN90U)
[image]

But in my website, (I made sure I used the same Bootstrap and Masonry-Layout version), it's having issues with margin-bottom. The issue is that it ignores the margin-bottom entirely.

[image]

Anyone might have an idea why it's not following what codeply's example is doing?

Comment: There is no proper solution to this. I came back from work, and it fixed itself. Might be cache issue.